# Using Free-Form-Deformation (or similar technique) in Web

Tags: javascript, react-native, image-processing, transformation

Our AI model recognizes an object in an image and creates a mask on it.
It returns a raster image of mask that covers the detected object.

Here have a look at this example:

[image]

Now the black outline is what AI model gives us, and sometimes it makes little errors setting the boundary around the object like shown in red rectangle in the image.

I want to allow the user to correct this outline by dragging the outline.

One way that comes to my mind is to use Free Form Deformation or something similar but I don't know how to do that in React Native, I can't find a library etc. (and don't have much time to implement it from scratch)

Someone please give me a direction on this, Thank you.

Comment: If the outline is only available as this black curve overlay, you'll first have to extract the curve and discretize it with a free-form curve such as a cubic spline. But maybe the outline is available in another form ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust The outline here is just an example, We actually get a raster image with pixels only on highlighted area.

I assumed we can vectorize it and extract a low-vertex polygon from it. OR we can just apply deformation on the actual raster image without vectorization etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you know coordinates you can use Skia and SVG paths https://shopify.github.io/react-native-skia/docs/shapes/path/ to draw your boundary and using Canvas touch handlers you can allow users to change coordinates.

Example of path building: https://youtu.be/7SCzL-XnfUU

Or this example of a hand drawing app: https://medium.com/react-native-rocket/building-a-hand-drawing-app-with-react-native-skia-and-gesture-handler-9797f5f7b9b4

And this example https://blog.notesnook.com/drawing-app-with-react-native-skia/